# I am missing a lifecycle initialization method after _ready()

Tags: lifecycle, godot, gdscript

Disclaimer: new in Godot here. Some experience with Unity

I am doing the initialization of my scripts into the `_ready()` method.

But I am missing a method that is automatically called on each script after all the `_ready()` methods have finished for all the Nodes in the scene. I understand that this is when all the tree has been loaded.

The reason is that in the `_ready()` method I initialize the actual script's internal state. But if I need to make some initialization, adjustments, and setup, into the scripts referenced by this one I need to be sure I do them after the `_ready()` method has finished on all that objects.

I see that this is the lifecycle of scripts in Godot:

- https://github.com/godotengine/godot-docs/issues/5492

This is the same in Unity:

- https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

As I am understanding the Godot's `_ready()` is equivalent to the `Awake()` in Unity.

I am missing in Godot what would be the equivalent of `Start()` in Unity. Which is called after all the objects have been initialized.

Does this method exist? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do your initialization in a function called `do_setup` and then call this function deferred in the next frame by doing: `call_deferred("do_setup")`
If you do this in `_ready` the next frame will be the first frame of the game.

Like so:

```
func _ready():
    call_deferred("do_setup")
    
func do_setup():
    # Do initialization here
```

Docs:
https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-call-deferred

Answer (score 3):

Godot calls the `_ready` method after it has called the `_ready` for all the children `Node`s. Thus, a first solution is to do your post-initialization on the `_ready` of the scene root. *I'll get back to this below.*

*When I say scene root, I mean the `Node` that is the root of the scene where your `Node` is (i.e. it's `owner`)*

On the other hand, when the `Node`s are first instantiated Godot will call `_init`. Which always happens before `_ready`, but the `Node` won't be in the scene tree, so if your initialization requires to access the scene tree that is not useful…

If you need to access the scene tree, consider using `_enter_tree`. Godot will call `_enter_tree` when it adds the `Node` to the scene tree, which first happens before `_ready`. Note that if you remove it and add it again, Godot will call `_enter_tree` again.

*I would argue that `_init` is closer to Unity's `Awake` or `Reset`, and `_ready` is the `Start` you want. Perhaps you should be using `_init` or `_enter_tree` for your initialization. Or perhaps the `_ready` you need is not the one on your `Node`…*

---

If you need the `_ready` of the scene root (i.e. the `owner` of your `Node`), but you don't want to put your initialization code on the scene root, you can connect to it. Something like this:

```
func _ready() -> void:
    owner.connect("ready", self, "_on_scene_ready")


func _on_scene_ready() -> void:
    print("the scene is ready")
```

Notes and caveats:

- Godot sends the `"ready"` signal happens after it has already called the `_ready`  method.
- If Godot sent the `"ready"` signal it won't send it again (unless the `Node`s - i.e. the root of the scene - is removed from the scene tree, ready is requested, and then it is added to the scene tree again).
- The presented code stops at scene boundaries. *I'll get back to that.*
- Because of the prior point, this connection is also possible form the editor.

As I said above, when I say scene root, I mean the `Node` that is the root of the scene where your `Node` is (i.e. it's `owner`)… What if you want the current scene (the one you change with `get_tree().change_scene(…)`)? Well, you can get it with `get_tree().current_scene` so you can do this:

```
func _ready() -> void:
    get_tree().current_scene.connect("ready", self, "_on_scene_ready")


func _on_scene_ready() -> void:
    print("the scene is ready")
```

*You could also do it with the `root` of the whole scene tree `get_tree().root`, which is the parent of the current scene and whatever you have autoloaded. I don't know how useful that would be. Yet be aware that the `root` of the scene tree does not change, so it would be once per game execution.*